# How do I get the key values from $_POST and also that value in which i have field the data?

Tags: php, forms, key, submit, key-value

I have a form in which there are 150 fields and I want to send only that key & value in an email which I have filled in the form on the time of submitting,  not all value.

Currently On "$_POST" it is showing all key and value but I want only that value which I have filled in the input text.

EDIT

On submit form and print $_POST i have its print like this

```
[a] => 11 
[b] => 11 
[c] => 11 
[d] => 11 
[d] => 
[e] => 
[f] => 
[d] =>
```

But i want that key and value both which have data

Comment: `$_POST=array_filter( $_POST );` ?

Comment: So pick the values out of `$_POST` that you are interested in and ignore the rest

Comment: @Ram  Thanks for your comment , i also want key value

Comment: Hi , its not really clear what you are asking here. If you can provide an example maybe we can help

Comment: On submit form and print $_POST i have its print like this 

[a] => 11
[b] => 11
[c] => 11
[d] => 11
[d] => 
[e] => 
[f] => 
[d] => 

But i want that key and value both which have data

Comment: using $_POST=array_filter( $_POST ); i get the correct data but how do i get key value

Comment: `array_keys( $_POST )`

Comment: There are 150 fields , so how can i define 150 field in email to send data, i want to send key and value both dynamic in email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if($value!='') {
        $post[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

I think it may help you. `$post` will have all the data that you need.

Comment: Yes, all value and also key of that value , because i have to send both in email key and value of that key

Comment: I am also getting the "submit - SUBMIT" value in print_r , how i exclude this

Comment: I am also getting the "submit - SUBMIT" value in print_r , how i exclude this

Comment: you can use `array_pop` to delete the last element from array

Answer (score 1):

Considering your post data as follows:

```
$_POST = array(
    'a' => '11', 
    'b' => 11, 
    'c' => 11, 
    'd' => null, 
    'e' => null, 
);

$to_delete = array(0 => false);
print_r(array_diff($_POST, $to_delete));
```

The working code is here: https://3v4l.org/BZVQn

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep one extra hidden input field to store old value for each input element of your form. So if your form has 150 input element then there will be another 150 hidden fields and overall there will be 300 fields in the form (150 visible on the page and remaining 150 will not be visible to the user).

Initially, when the page loads, both the input element and the hidden element will have the same data but the user can change only visible input element and can submit the form.

In the PHP script, where this form post the data, you need to compare values of input element VS hidden element. If they are not the same then add new value in a new temporary array. This new temporary array will be used while sending the email.

Example:

**Form**

```
field_1
hidden_field_1

field_2
hidden_field_2

field_3
hidden_field_3
```

**PHP**

```
loop on $_POST array {
    if ( hidden_field_1 != field_1) {
        // Store field_1 in temp to send it in email
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also getting the "submit - SUBMIT" value in print_r , how i exclude this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I am understanding your requirement correctly, you could do this in a simple foreach loop

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
    if ( $key == 'submit' ) {
        continue;
    }
    echo $key . " = " . $val . '<br>';
}
```

If there is more than one field then you can create an ignore list and text each field name against it.

```
$ignore_list = ['submit', 'other_field'];

foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
    if ( in_array($key, $ignore_list ) {
        continue;
    }
    echo $key . " = " . $val . '<br>';
}
```

Of course you can make the generated output look however you want I just used a simple `echo` for demo purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Comment: I am also getting the "submit - SUBMIT" value in print_r , how i exclude this

Comment: @Sheenu I have amended my answer to not report the submit button

Answer (score 0):

As an example of how `array_filter` will alter the final POST array consider the following demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>multiple fields, non-empty only selected</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <?php
                /* for brevity only 10 results */
                for( $i=1; $i <= 10; $i++ ){
                    $checked = rand(0,5)==1 ? $i : '';
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='field_$i' value='$checked' />";
                }

                if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
                    /* results without filtering */
                    printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $_POST, 1 ) );


                    /* results AFTER filtering */
                    $_POST=array_filter( $_POST );
                    printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $_POST, 1 ) );
                }
            ?>
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example output:

```
Array
(
    [field_1] => 1
    [field_2] => 
    [field_3] => 3
    [field_4] => 
    [field_5] => 5
    [field_6] => 
    [field_7] => 
    [field_8] => 
    [field_9] => 
    [field_10] => 10
)
Array
(
    [field_1] => 1
    [field_3] => 3
    [field_5] => 5
    [field_10] => 10
)
```

The output of the two `print` statements are vastly different - the use of `array_filter` has removed all the empty form fields from the array - from that point processing of the array data is trivial using `foreach` or another method such as `array_walk`, `array_map` etc